# Best way to avoid copy-paste and hardcoding

Tags: python, design-patterns

' Hello, SO community.

**Problem:** I have many regEx patterns, such as

```
r'to.*school', r'built.*in'
```

and etc. In every case, I should execute a code, that varies from situation to situation.

**Example:** If pattern is 'to.*school', I want to find the verb before 'to' and that's why I write something like:

```
for num, part in enumerate(sentence):
    if part == 'to':
        result = sentence[num-1]
```

If pattern is 'built.*in', I want to find the time and that's why I write something like:

```
for num, part in enumerate(sentence):
    if part == 'in':
        result = sentence[num+1]
```

So there's the problem - how can I avoid copy-pasting code, if there's over 500 patterns and each pattern has its own way to get result?

**My thoughts:** I understand it should be some kind of database, which stores patterns and solutions, but how do I execute solution, if it's a string? I'm totally lost.

Comment: Can you show an example of `sentence` and your desired output?

Comment: I would introduce a table which contains in the first column the patterns and in the second one a reference to an appropriate method.

Comment: @Chris_Rands of course. `origSentence = 'I go to school'; pattern = r'to.*school'; partSentence = ['I', 'go', 'to', 'school']; result = 'go';`

Comment: @Humbalan that's what I'm trying to perform, using MongoDB. But my supervisor says he doesn't want to edit source code whenever new pattern is added and that's why I need to come up with solution when everything is hidden in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is sufficient regularity in the code you need to write a function which accepts sentence and the other things which determine what to do with it. This is sometimes called parametrisation. For example with your above, presumably simplified examples, you'd have

```
def process(sentence, parttest, offset):
    for num, part in enumerate(sentence):
        if part == parttest:
            return sentence[num+offset]
```

and calls for first and second examples respectively

```
result = process( sentence, 'to', -1)
result2 = process( sentence, 'in', +1)
```

Now you can obtain the parameters (parttest, offset) from a database. Judging from your post there may also be a regular expression in string form to be retrieved from the database as well, and `process` to be extended to include a regular expression string which is compiled on demand.

Optimize later: keep a local cache of compiled regular expressions in a dict, or pickle them, because repeatedly compiling the same one may be a nontrivial waste of CPU.

Hope this helps.